# CLLocation authorisation popup alert auto dismiss

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

Why alert for authorisation of getting location auto dismiss after 2 sec and as I don't have any authorisation so delegates are not working? Any help? I am not using ARC.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I am using ARC. You can see that immediately after the alertview appears, the delegate method
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
is called. Probably a bug.

Comment: I confirm that my problem was the nilling of the manager (even if it was an instance variable). I was observing app deactivation notifications to avoid using the manager, but when the alertview pops up, the app becomes de facto inactive...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using ARC so keep in mind that the `manager` has to be an instance variable (not local) otherwise it gets released!

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens if you have the location manager as variable instead of attribute. When the method (usually viewDidLoad) reaches its end, it deallocates the variable and the auth pop up disappears.